# Entity has no persistent id property when extracting a superclass from @EmbeddedId class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using Spring Boot 1.3 with Spring Data JPA. I have want to use early primary key generation using a dedicated object for the primary key (As advised in [Implementing Domain Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321834577)).

Suppose this entity:

```
@Entity
public class Book {
  @EmbeddedId
  private BookId id;
}
```

and this value object:

```
@Embeddable
public class BookId implements Serializable {

  private UUID id;

  protected BookId(){} //for hibernate

  public BookId( UUID id ) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public UUID getId() {
    return id;
  }
}
```

Then this works fine. However, I want to create a superclass for all id classes, something like:

```
public class EntityUuidId implements Serializable {

  private UUID id;

  protected EntityUuidId(){} //for hibernate

  public EntityUuidId( UUID id ) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public UUID getId() {
    return id;
  }
}
```

Now the BookId class changes to:

```
@Embeddable
public class BookId extends EntityUuidId {

  protected BookId(){} //for hibernate

  public BookId( UUID id ) {
    super(id);
  }
}
```

The problem is now when I run my application there is the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: BookId has no persistent id property: Book.id
```

Why does that suddenly not work anymore?

Comment: indeed, because "id" is not part of any JPA annotated class, hence is not persistent. You could have getter/setter for the id on the subclass.

Comment: I'm not sure if `@MappedSupperclass` can be used as `@Embeddable`'s parent, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: EclipseLink seems to support it: [link](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=283028)

Comment: Works with Hibernate as well, I just tested. Please add your comment as a real answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put `@MappedSuperclass` on `EntityUuidId` class, that way its properties will be treated as persistent.